# Apache Rewrite rule having # in url

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect urls having 'cms/ZeUI/logout' to ++resource++core/nurse_login/index.html#/logout internally but in browser the URL should still be cms/ZeUI/logout in browser.I tried using below rule
RewriteRule "^/cms/ZeUI/logout(.*)$" "++resource++core/nurse_login/index.html#/logout" [NE,R=301,L]. But,the url is changing in the browser. Tried with Rewrite Rule "^/cms/ZeUI/logout(.*)$" "++resource++core/nurse_login/index.html#/logout" [PT]. But, it is unable to process #/logout in the URL. Any other flag is there to achieve the same.

Comment: Is your server-side script expecting to process a fragment identifier (fragid)?! (Although if you have a `index.html` file - what server-side scripting language are you using?)

Comment: Please including some (code) formatting in your question to make it easier to read. Thanks. (Indent 4 spaces or use "backtick fencing" for code blocks, backticks for inline code, etc.)

Comment: "it is unable to process #/logout in the URL" - Because I suspect your _server (script)_ is not expecting to process the fragid. Ordinarily, fragid's (everything after the `#`) are only processed client-side (by HTML/JavaScript) - they are not passed to the server as part of the HTTP request (the browser strips it). So, rewriting the request server-side to include a fragid does not usually make sense.

Comment: ...and where exactly are you using these mod_rewrite directives? (The regex would suggest in the main server config somewhere, as opposed to `.htaccess`?)

Comment: I am using zope server side language to process this.